# <HTML> is automatically setting inline-style that I think is set by Google's JSAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I bought the [Roker](http://themeforest.net/item/roker-corporate-creative-multi-purpose-teme/6354076?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=iwthemes) theme from [themeforest.net](http://themeforest.net) and created my website. It works fine and looks great but when I try to open my website on a Windows touch device - Surface Pro (IE and Firefox) or Windows Phone, I cannot scroll with my finger i.e. touch is not working.

When I look at the HTML code, the rendered page’s  tag is adding this style

```
-ms-overflow-x: hidden; -ms-overflow-y: hidden; -ms-touch-action: auto !important;
```

And the overflow is set as an inline style.

This seems to get set automatically when I include the Google's [JSAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide), because when I comment the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`, then everything works fine.

Any suggestions on how can I overcome this? I can share the link of my website if you want to see what is happening yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to track down the js file and find out why it is adding those inline styles.

I have a feeling it may have to do with the 'no-touch' class. You may want to use something like the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        detectMsTouch();

        function detectMsTouch() {
            var touchPoints = window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints; 
            if (touchPoints) {
                $('html').removeClass('no-touch').addClass('touch');

            }
            else {
                return;
            }
        }   
    });
```

Another thing that may work is forcing the style with a CSS override.

```
ms-overflow-y: visible !important;
```

Hope it works for you.